# Raspberry PI: Turning LED On/OFF via server

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

I'm i have created a server/ using the raspberry pi as a server and connected LED lights to to a breadboard at GPIO 7...

I am using this script:

```
<html>
 <head>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['RedON']))
{ exec('sudo python /var/www/on.py');
}
if (isset($_POST['RedOFF']))
{
exec('sudo python off.py');
}
?>

  <title>Hub</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
  <table
 style="width: 75%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
 border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">Turn LED on</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">Turn LED off</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="RedON">Red On</button></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="RedOFF">Red Off</button></td>
      </tr>
    </body>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when i click the buttons ON/OFF nothing works.

If i run the sudo commands itself, IE: sudo python off.py it works, however when placing it in the script it doesn't work

Comment: Your buttons are just buttons. You need `<input type='submit'...>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried listening the console output? probably your script is working but it has no sudo pass.

You can set the php permisions to sudo, but i wouldnt.

try setting chmod 777x and chown all:all to your python script

Answer (score 1):

you should use an action in your form,its good practice.

> form action="page.php" method="post">

also,you can use print_r($_POST); at the top of the page to check what youre receiving from the inputs you gave

Comment: If the action attribute is empty the form will reload itself.

Comment: Yeah, but this was my draft version.. afterwords I improve the code when i get it working. Thanks for the tip anyway